# ReSharper Custom Pattern to Ignore Path Not Found Warning

Tags: resharper

How can I configure ReSharper to ignore the following Path Not Found Error?

```
<img src="icon.ashx?name=navLeft&size=24" alt="">
```

The warning is "Path icon.ashx not found".  The format for the path is "icon.ashx?name={0}&size={1}".

Can I add a custom pattern in ReSharper options to hide this warning for the entire application?  if so, what would the Search Pattern look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JetBrains Support:

There's no such option to ignore any inspection results using Custom Pattern.
I'd suggest to use pattern to find such matches and then disable them manually.
Try creating the following pattern: 

where $test$ is attribute value placeholder that should match to the following regex: (icon).(ashx)\?(name)=\w*&(size)=\d* and $attributes$ is any number of attributes.
Thank you.